# How to fit the title to the entire page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fit this title to the entire page. For some reason, there is a padding around the text that's not allowing me to fit it. I set the padding of the column (Bootstrap) to 0, but that doesn't seem to help. As soon as I increase the font-size > 230px, it just bleeds into the second line. Can someone help me?

Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUwAk.jpg. How the blue area doesn't snap to the end of the screen.

CSS:

```
 <style>
     body {
        background-color:black;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    div {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    .header {
        color:white;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeueLight", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", 'TeXGyreHerosRegular', "Helvetica", "Tahoma", "Geneva", "Arial";
    }

    .box {
        background-color:aqua;
    }

    #titlebig {
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:232px;
        text-align:left;
        margin-left:-29px;
        margin-top:-76px;
    }

    .row-no-padding {
      [class*="col-"] {
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
      }
    }

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid header">
        <!-- Grid structure -->
        <div class="row row-no-padding">
                <div id="titlebig" class="col-xs-12 box">
                    Let's Create
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove `margin-left: -29px;` from `#titlebig`. For example:

```css
body {
       background-color: black;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
     }
     div {
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
     }
     .header {
       color: white;
       font-family: "HelveticaNeueLight", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", 'TeXGyreHerosRegular', "Helvetica", "Tahoma", "Geneva", "Arial";
     }
     .box {
       background-color: aqua;
     }
     #titlebig {
       font-weight: normal;
       font-size: 232px;
       text-align: left;
       margin-left: -29px;
       margin-top: -76px;
     }
     .row-no-padding {
       [class*="col-"] {
         padding-left: 0 !important;
         padding-right: 0 !important;
       }
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid header">
    <div class="row row-no-padding">
      <div id="titlebig" class="col-xs-12 box">
        Let's Create
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Removing the margin-left just moves the title right, but doesn't expand it to the full page. I'm looking to get an effect something like this. http://40.media.tumblr.com/fe8a2a9c50d7f8151f193468de954242/tumblr_nqc4sgCPlM1ury09io2_r1_1280.png

Comment: That link is using an image though. It's pretty simple to scale an image to window width (`width: 100%`)

Comment: Yea, that would be acceptable and last resort. But I  was thinking I should be able to get that effect using css and regular text as well.

Comment: Scaling text isn't always a good idea really. It's very difficult to get the fonts to fit to widths perfectly.

Comment: Thanks David. I learned a lesson hardway. Spent over 4 hours trying to scale text. I just exported those image assets from sketch and set scaling on them. It works like a charm now.

Answer (score -1):

Because `col-xs-*` includes `float: left` per https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3487898a6af8c1d5b12f7b040d30e71b19e34923/less/mixins/grid.less#L24.

If you remove the col-xs-12 class, it will be full width.

With that said, you don't need the row class either. If you are just trying to have a full width div that goes edge to edge and wraps text correctly, you are describing an unstyled block element, of which div is one.

Comment: Removing the `col-*` is not how Bootstrap should work. Also, OP has put it in a fluid container which is full screen width.

Comment: Valid point. The OP doesn't need row either. If you are trying to just have a div that is the full width of a containing div, all you need to do is make an unstyled div. A block element does by default what is being asked.